# not able to get values from spinner to save image in internal storage,i have write the code for spinner but didnt get values

Tags: android

I have 2 spinners and I want to select a spinner and then save image from button to internal storage. I have already wrote the code for the spinner and button but I am not getting values of spinner, so whenever I select the same spinner category, I get the image that I have saved.

I have already wrote the code of spinner and base64.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        Spinner s1,s2;
        TextView t2;
        Button b1,b2;
        String doc="";
        ImageView i1;
        private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
        private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/digi360";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
            b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadbtn);
            i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
            // Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (sp1.contentEquals("B.Tech")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Select");
                list.add("ET");
                list.add("Maths");
                list.add("TOC");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                s2.setSelection(0);
                s2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                i1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (sp1.contentEquals("BBA")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Select");
                list.add("Business");
                list.add("Manage");
                list.add("Hotel");
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                s2.setSelection(0);
                s2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                t2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                i1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (sp1.contentEquals("Select")) {

                s2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                t2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                i1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    chooseImage();
                }
            });

            //////////////////////////////DATA READ AND WRITE/////////////////////////////
            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    String s1data = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String s2data = s2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                    i1.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap bitmap = i1.getDrawingCache();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
                    Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(MainActivity.getResources() , IMAGE_DIRECTORY).getBitmap();
                    int nh = (int) ( d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()) );
                    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
                    i1.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
                    byte[] image=stream.toByteArray();
                    // System.out.println("byte array:"+image);

                    String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, 0);
                    // System.out.println("string:"+img_str);

                    doc = s1data + "-" + s2data + "-" + img_str;
                    String filename = "digi360";
                    String data = doc;

                    FileOutputStream fos;
                    try {
                        fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        //default mode is PRIVATE, can be APPEND etc.
                        fos.write(data.getBytes());
                        fos.close();

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), filename + " saved",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    String filename = "mydata";
                    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                    try {
                        //Attaching BufferedReader to the FileInputStream by the help of InputStreamReader
                        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                openFileInput(filename)));
                        String inputString;
                        //Reading data line by line and storing it into the stringbuffer
                        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //Displaying data on the toast
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stringBuffer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        //////////////////IMAGE HANDLING//////////////////////////////////        
        public void chooseImage() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));


                    i1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

I need to store some values of spinner so I get my image that I have saved using save spinner.

Comment: Reformatted code, fixed grammar/spelling.

Answer (score 0):

you must `setArray` to your `sp1` first :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        t2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbutton);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loadbtn);
        i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     String[] stringArray = MainActivity.this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnner1);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringArray);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: i am new, so i am not able to fix this, as i want to select spinner then add image , then add image according to the values of spinner in folder and view it on choosing same value of spinner  and it also showing bitmap too large to be upload into a texture. can u help